# How to get object value when changed select option - Angular9

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ngfor

How to get object value when changed select option

```
items = [
{
  name:"Same",
  age:14,
  address:"Thailand"
},
{
  name:"Peter",
  age:30,
  address:"Thailand"
}
]
```

```
<select class="custom-select" (change)="selectItem($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" value="{{item}}" >
       {{item.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Can I use `selectItem` to get Object value with

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address: string;
}

public selectItem(data: Person) {
    console.log('==> data:', data);
    this.name = data.name;
    this.age = data.age;
    this.address = data.address
  }
```

but my console.log is `page: [object Object]`
I want it to be `page: {name:"Same" ,age:14 ,address:"Thailand"}` sometimes like that

Comment: not solve it can't call `item` outside `ngFor`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to us [ngValue] on your `<option>` elements.  When you use `[value]` its binding to the elements value attribute which is a string, `[ngValue]` allows you to bind an object.

You also need to add a binding model `[ngModel]` and then bind to `(ngModelChange)` event rather than `(change)`.  See stackblitz below for a working example...

```html
<select class="custom-select" #sel [ngModel]="sel" (ngModelChange)="selectItem($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item" >
       {{item.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bmnkl1

> https://trungk18.com/experience/angular-select-option-value-ngvalue/

Answer (score 2):

**Use Like following:**

**`app.component.ts`**

```
  public selectItem(data: any) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log("==> data:", data);
    this.name = data.name;
    this.age = data.age;
    this.address = data.address;
  }

  stringify(val: any) {
    return JSON.stringify(val);
  }
```

**`app.component.html`**

```
<select #sel class="custom-select" (change)="selectItem(sel.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" value="{{stringify(item)}}" >
       {{item.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Working Example: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cq8upg?file=src/app/app.component.html**